# 1D and 2D array initialization with braces

Tags: c

The following code gives an "invalid initializer" error:

```
     int a[]=(1,2,3);
```

But the following compiles successfully although it considers ','  as comma OPERATOR and not SEPARATOR:

```
    int a[][2]={(1,2),(3,4)};
```

So why is `()` invalid for a 1D array and not for a 2D array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first example:

```
int a[]=(1,2,3);
```

the initializer is a (rather odd) expression of type `int`. (It contains two comma operators, and yields the value `3`.) The object is an array. The initialization is invalid because it's a type mismatch.

The second:

```
int a[][2]={(1,2),(3,4)};
```

is equivalent to:

```
int a[][2] = { 2, 4 };
```

which is valid because it's permissible to omit nested curly braces in an initializer; elements are used to initialize successive elements of the object.  The first and third commas are comma operators; the second is a delimiter.

The outermost curly braces are *optional* if the initializer is simply an expression of the target type, whether it's a scalar, struct, or union. For example, you can write:

```
int x = 42;
int y = { 42 };
```

The outermost curly braces are *required* for an initializer that specifies element values (for an array, struct, or union object).

For example:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

 struct foo arr[2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

is valid -- but it's more clearly written as:

```
 struct foo arr[2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

Apart from the first example being invalid, both are poor style.  The first may have been intended to be:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and the second either:

```
int a[][2] = { 2, 4 };
```

or

```
int a[][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

depending on the intent.

Comment: I agree with your answer but the statement "outermost curly braces are for array struct initialization" I think is not true you can use them with scalars as well like int,char but it will return only the first element

Comment: @SaurabhMehta: I said the outermost braces are *required* for array, struct, and union initialization (unless, now that I think of it, the initializer is an object of struct or union type). Braces are *optional* for a scalar initializer.

Comment: @SaurabhMehta: Sorry, I should have written "expression", not "object", in my previous comment. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the curly braces in the first example. The accolades (curly braces) denote the initialisation of the contents of the array, the contents are then handled by your declarations within those accolades. Basically you're not initialisating the array in the first example. The parenthesis denote the order of evaluation, not arguments as they do with functions.

Comment: No, `(1, 2, 3)` is an expression of type `int` with the value `3`. The initializer is invalid because of the type mismatch. See my answer. (It may well have been the *intent* to use braces rather than parentheses, but I think the question is about why this particular code is not accepted.)